# Problem with composite_primary_key Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I'm using the composite primary keys gem from drnic and I've got a problem with it:
If I want to create a CourseOrder (with has a cpk) with the following command in my tests: `course_order = CourseOrder.new(:daily_order => daily_orders(:daily_order_one_of_today_for_hans),:course => courses(:non_veg_2), :finished => false, :ordered_at => Time.now)` I'll get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  null value in column "course_iddaily_order_id" violates not-null constraint
>   : INSERT INTO "course_orders" ("course_iddaily_order_id", "course_id", "ordered_at", "finished", "daily_order_id") VALUES (NULL, 489519433, '2011-03-01 10:19:27.169397', 'f', 594369222) RETURNING "course_iddaily_order_id"

I think that there is a course_iddaily_order_id is wrong, isn't it?

My Migration file looks like this:

```
class AddCourseOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :course_orders, :primary_key => [:course_id, :daily_order_id] do |table|
      table.integer :course_id
      table.integer :daily_order_id
      table.datetime :ordered_at, :null => false
      table.boolean :finished, :default => false, :null => false
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :course_orders
  end
end
```

The resulting schema part looks like this:

```
  create_table "course_orders", :primary_key => "course_iddaily_order_id", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "course_id",                         :null => false
    t.integer  "daily_order_id",                    :null => false
    t.datetime "ordered_at",                        :null => false
    t.boolean  "finished",       :default => false, :null => false
 end
```

My Model looks like this:

```
class CourseOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_keys :course_id, :daily_order_id
  belongs_to :course 
  belongs_to :daily_order
end
```

I don't know whats wrong here, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `create_table` method doesn't takes an array for `:primary_key` option. I guess you can omit setting it.

Comment: I think the "composite_primary_key" gem should implement exactly that feature.